# Как правильнее оформить функции для SPA-сайта?

Tags: javascript, функции, dom, spa

Всем привет.
Как правильнее внедрять DOM на страницу,получая массив элементов через ajax-запрос к БД? Три нюанса:

1. элементам нужно назначать addEventListener (клик для роутера, что-то еще).
2. внедреннный дом надо будет заменять на другой (из списка товаров перехожу на один товар и назад).
3. все асинхроннно.

В общем стандартный SPA.

Вопрос в правильном оформлении функции, вижу два варианта:

1. Получил массив товаров. Передаю массив в функцию. Результат
   выполнения функции добавляю в DOM.
2. Получил массив товаров. Передаю массив в функцию. Функция добавляет результат в DOM.

HTML типовой - `<div id="app"></div>`

Куски кода ниже, оба варианта откомментил:

```
var app = document.getElementById('app');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    getMainPage();
}

//получаем из БД вложенный массив items, товары здесь: items['products']
function getMainPage(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('send_name', 'get_main_page');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.responseType =  "json";
    request.open('POST', '/api/ajax.php', true);
    request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var items = this.response;

            //ПЕРВЫЙ ВАРИАНТ
            var get_products = showProducts(items);
            app.appendChild(get_products);

            //или ВТОРОЙ ВАРИАНТ
            showProducts(items);
        }
    });
    request.send(formData);
}

//формируем из полученного массива items список ссылок на товары в виде ul-li
function showProducts(items) {
    var products = items['products'];
    var product_list = document.createElement('ul');
    product_list.className = 'product_list';
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        var product = document.createElement('li');

        //ссылка на товар
        var product_name = document.createElement('a');
        product_name.className = 'product_name';
        product_name.href = 'items/' + products[i].id;
        product_name.textContent = products[i].name;
        product_name.addEventListener('click', product_nav);//функция роутинга

        //блоки с ценой и характеристиками опущены
        product.appendChild(product_name);
        product_list.appendChild(product);
    }

    //ПЕРВЫЙ ВАРИАНТ
    return product_list;

    //или ВТОРОЙ ВАРИАНТ
    app_box.appendChild(product_list);
}
```

Comment: Лучше разделить обязанности. Одна функция строит дом элементы, вторая их добавляет\обновялет.

Comment: Т.е. итого три функции? Первая получает массив с сервера, вторая строит из массива дом, третья построенный дом добавляет на стр?

Comment: Да, все верно. Иногда может понадобится даже четвертая функция - привязка событий, если их много или там сложная логика.